# How to add advertising in .Net Maui?

Tags: android, ios, admob, maui, ads

I'm developing in .Net Maui, .Net 7.0, Windows 11 with Visual Studio 2022 17.8.0.
I'm trying to add ads from Google AdMob in my project.

I use 'Plugin.MauiMTAdmob 1.0.4'. I was able to install it and works for Android but not for iOS.
For iOS, the plugin uses "Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Core" as a dependency but is impossible to use. "Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Core" has a long path inside and the editor cannot work.

this is the error I get while compiling:

```
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\g\AppData\Local\Temp\Xamarin\HotRestart\Signing\MauiAds.app\out\Payload\MauiAds.app\MauiAds.content\Firebase.Core.resources\FirebaseCoreDiagnostics.xcframework\ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator\FirebaseCoreDiagnostics.framework\Headers\FIRCoreDiagnostics.h'.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
   at System.IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions.DoCreateEntryFromFile(ZipArchive destination, String sourceFileName, String entryName, Nullable`1 compressionLevel)
   at System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.DoCreateFromDirectory(String sourceDirectoryName, String destinationArchiveFileName, Nullable`1 compressionLevel, Boolean includeBaseDirectory, Encoding entryNameEncoding)
   at Xamarin.iOS.Windows.Installer.ApplicationSession.CreateIpa(String appName, String appPath, String targetPath) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Tools\Xamarin.iOS.Windows.Client\Installer\ApplicationSession.cs:line 238
   at Xamarin.iOS.Windows.Installer.ApplicationSession.Deploy(String appRootFolder, String appBundleId, String appName) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Tools\Xamarin.iOS.Windows.Client\Installer\ApplicationSession.cs:line 91
   at Xamarin.iOS.Windows.HotRestartClient.Deploy(AppleDevice nativeDevice, String appBundleId, String appBundleName, Boolean& incremental) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Tools\Xamarin.iOS.Windows.Client\HotRestartClient.cs:line 250
```

I also find this problem open [here](https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents/issues/555), but none of these solutions worked for me.

What is the best solution? I should try to use another advertising provider? If yes, do you know how canI do it?